# Print Lines Between Two Patterns with SED

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I have a file with the content shown below:

```
***************Encrypted String***************
 ezF7LcHO0Zlb+8kkBeIwtA== 
**********************************************
```

I need to get only encrypted password from above. I used Google to search for an answer, and I got this example (below), but it didn't work:

```
sed -n '/***************Encrypted String***************/,/************************************‌​**********/p' $file
```

I tried but it didn't work

Comment: what have you tried? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns/38978201#38978201 for an example to solve this kind of problem

Comment: sed -n '/BEGIN/,/END/p' $file but it did not work

Comment: actually i need to get only encrypted password from below. While i am google it i got above example but it didn't work
***************Encrypted String***************
ezF7LcHO0Zlb+8kkBeIwtA==
**********************************************

Comment: sed -n '/BEGIN/,/END/{/BEGIN/!{/END/!p}}' file

Comment: i need to get only encrypted password from below. While i am google it i got above example but it didn't work 
***************Encrypted String*************** 
ezF7LcHO0Zlb+8kkBeIwtA== 
**********************************************
sed -n '/***************Encrypted String***************/,/**********************************************/p' $file
is this works, i tryed but it didn't work

Comment: Please put your updates into the question. Leaving them in the comments makes it confusing and ambiguous for people trying to understand which is the most recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is probably that `*` is a Regular Expression operator, so you have to escape it `\*` for it to be treated as a literal. Your examples and suggestions referencing the literals `BEGIN` and `END` would all have failed without this adaptation.

> ```
> ***************Encrypted String***************
>  ezF7LcHO0Zlb+8kkBeIwtA== 
> **********************************************
> ```

To extract the second line you could use either of these:

```
sed -n '0,/\*Encrypted String\*/d;p;q' "$file"
sed -n 2p "$file"
```

The first matches on `*Encrypted String*` and then prints the next line. Notice that the `*` characters are written as `\*` to ensure they are treated as literal asterisks. The second just prints line two of the file.